# does logstash's elasticsearch output plugin retry individual bulk errors?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, logstash

context: logstash elasticsearch output plugin.

When an individual action in a bulk request fails, will it be retried in a following bulk request? (or the individual request is lost?)

documentation on this is not very clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like plugin parses the response and processes each action result separately - [Plugin code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/c56322b23f81fb0711fc86e86d0944e6e752fbd9/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb#L131)

So the following retry police works for an individual action - [Plugin retry policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_retry_policy)

Example of the bad response:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "errors": true, 
   "items": [
      {  "create": {
            "_index":   "website",
            "_type":    "blog",
            "_id":      "123",
            "status":   409, 
            "error":    "DocumentAlreadyExistsException 
                        [[website][4] [blog][123]:
                        document already exists]"
      }},
      {  "index": {
            "_index":   "website",
            "_type":    "blog",
            "_id":      "123",
            "_version": 5,
            "status":   200 
      }}
   ]
}
```